# Change text click on the button

Tags: vb.net

I decide to use button to display AM/PM, when click on the button I want to change button text as AM to PM. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
If button1.Text = "AM" Then
  button1.Text = "PM"
Else
  button1.Text = "AM"
End If
```